# Tabs Widget JQuery not displaying correctly, Correct links already linked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, tabs

[Here is the code in JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ohw4rob/1/)

[or my Github for each file indvidually](https://github.com/CeliCel/celicel.github.io)

My tabs widget is still displaying as a list. I've linked the correct JS UI and CSS. I've looked over the documentation a hundred times and cannot see what I'm missing. It has to be an incorrect link I guess. The Tabs are displaying as lists.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Reservation request</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="reservationTab.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Reservation Request</h1>
    <form action="response.html" method="get"
        name="reservation_form" id="reservation_form">

        <div id ="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#tabs-1"> General Information </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#tabs-2"> Preferences </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#tabs-3"> Contact </a> </li>
            </ul>

            <div id="tabs-1">
                <label for="arrival_date">Arrival date:</label>
                <input type="text" name="arrival_date" id="arrival_date" placeholder="M/D/YYYY" autofocus>
                <span>*</span><br>
                <label for="nights">Nights:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nights" id="nights">
                <span>*</span><br>
                <label>Adults:</label>
                <select name="adults" id="adults">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>                                                
                </select><br>
                <label>Children:</label>
                <select name="children" id="children">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>                                                
                </select><br>           
            </div><!--tab1: genInfo-->

            <div id="tabs-2">
                <label>Room type:</label>
                <input type="radio" name="room" id="standard" class="left" checked>Standard&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;               
                <input type="radio" name="room" id="business" class="left">Business&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="room" id="suite" class="left last">Suite<br>
                <label>Bed type:</label>
                <input type="radio" name="bed" id="king" class="left" checked>King&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="bed" id="double" class="left last">Double Double<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="smoking" id="smoking">Smoking<br>
            </div> <!--tab2: Pref-->

            <div id="tabs-3">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                <span>*</span><br>
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
                <span>*</span><br>
                <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="999-999-9999">
                <span>*</span><br>
            </div> <!--tab3: contactInfo-->

        </div> <!--end tabs div-->



            <input type="button" id="policies" value="View Cancellation Policies">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Request">
            <div id="dialog" title="Cancellation Policies" style="display: none;">
                <p>Notification of cancellation or arrival date change must be 
                received more than three days (72 hours) prior to the confirmed arrival date for the 
                reservation deposit to be refundable. Email notification is acceptable, and a cancellation
                confirmation will be sent to you. Failure to check-in on the scheduled arrival date 
                will result in the cancellation of the reservation including any remaining nights, 
                and the reservation deposit shall be forfeited.</p>
            </div><br>          


    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var emailPattern = /\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b/;

// move the focus to the first text box
$("#arrival_date").focus();

//for tabs
$("#tabs").tabs();

// the handler for the submit event of the form
// executed when the submit button is clicked
$("#reservation_form").submit(
    function(event) {
        var isValid = true;

        // validate the requested arrival date
        var arrivalDate = $("#arrival_date").val().trim();
        if (arrivalDate == "") {
            $("#arrival_date").next().text("This field is required.");
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            $("#arrival_date").next().text("");             
        }
        $("#arrival_date").val(arrivalDate);

        // validate the number of nights
        var nights = $("#nights").val().trim();
        if (nights == "") {
            $("#nights").next().text("This field is required.");
            isValid = false;
        } else if (isNaN($("#nights").val())) {
            $("#nights").next().text("This field must be numeric.");
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            $("#nights").next().text("");
        }
        $("#nights").val(nights);       

        // validate the name entry
        var name = $("#name").val().trim();
        if (name == "") {
            $("#name").next().text("This field is required.");
            isValid = false;
        } 
        else {
            $("#name").val(name);
            $("#name").next().text("");
        }
        $("#name").val(name);

        // validate the email entry with a regular expression
        var email = $("#email").val();
        if (email == "") { 
            $("#email").next().text("This field is required.");
            isValid = false;
        } else if ( !emailPattern.test(email) ) {
            $("#email").next().text("Must be a valid email address.");
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            $("#email").next().text("");
        }
        $("#email").val(email); 

        // validate the phone number
        var phone = $("#phone").val().trim();
        if (phone == "") { 
            $("#phone").next().text("This field is required.");
            isValid = false; 
        } else {
            $("#phone").next().text("");
        }
        $("#phone").val(phone);

        // prevent the submission of the form if any entries are invalid 
        if (isValid == false) {
            event.preventDefault();             
        }
    } // end function
);  // end submit
}); // end ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var emailPattern = /\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b/;
 
 // move the focus to the first text box
 $("#arrival_date").focus();
 
 //for tabs
 $("#tabs").tabs();
 
 // the handler for the submit event of the form
 // executed when the submit button is clicked
 $("#reservation_form").submit(
  function(event) {
   var isValid = true;
   
   // validate the requested arrival date
   var arrivalDate = $("#arrival_date").val().trim();
   if (arrivalDate == "") {
    $("#arrival_date").next().text("This field is required.");
    isValid = false;
   } else {
    $("#arrival_date").next().text("");    
   }
   $("#arrival_date").val(arrivalDate);
   
   // validate the number of nights
   var nights = $("#nights").val().trim();
   if (nights == "") {
    $("#nights").next().text("This field is required.");
    isValid = false;
   } else if (isNaN($("#nights").val())) {
    $("#nights").next().text("This field must be numeric.");
    isValid = false;
   } else {
    $("#nights").next().text("");
   }
   $("#nights").val(nights);  

   // validate the name entry
   var name = $("#name").val().trim();
   if (name == "") {
    $("#name").next().text("This field is required.");
    isValid = false;
   } 
   else {
    $("#name").val(name);
    $("#name").next().text("");
   }
   $("#name").val(name);
      
   // validate the email entry with a regular expression
   var email = $("#email").val();
   if (email == "") { 
    $("#email").next().text("This field is required.");
    isValid = false;
   } else if ( !emailPattern.test(email) ) {
    $("#email").next().text("Must be a valid email address.");
    isValid = false;
   } else {
    $("#email").next().text("");
   }
   $("#email").val(email); 
   
   // validate the phone number
   var phone = $("#phone").val().trim();
   if (phone == "") { 
    $("#phone").next().text("This field is required.");
    isValid = false; 
   } else {
    $("#phone").next().text("");
   }
   $("#phone").val(phone);
   
   // prevent the submission of the form if any entries are invalid 
   if (isValid == false) {
    event.preventDefault();    
   }
  } // end function
 ); // end submit
}); // end ready
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 87.5%;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
legend {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: .8em;
}
label {
 float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
input, select {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
input {
    width: 14em; 
}
input.left {
 width: 1em;
 padding-left: 0;
}
fieldset {
 border: none;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-top: 1em;
 padding: 0;
}
input.last {
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}
#adults, #children {
 width: 35px;
}
#smoking {
 width: 1em;
 margin-left: 0;
}
#policies {
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 15em;
}
#submit {
 width: 10em;
}
#dialog p {
 font-size: 85%;
}
span {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Reservation request</title>
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI library -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body>
 <h1>Reservation Request</h1>
 <form action="response.html" method="get"
     name="reservation_form" id="reservation_form">
     
     <div id ="tabs">
      <ul>
       <li> <a href="#tabs-1"> General Information </a> </li>
       <li> <a href="#tabs-2"> Preferences </a> </li>
       <li> <a href="#tabs-3"> Contact </a> </li>
      </ul>
      
      <div id="tabs-1">
       <label for="arrival_date">Arrival date:</label>
          <input type="text" name="arrival_date" id="arrival_date" placeholder="M/D/YYYY" autofocus>
          <span>*</span><br>
          <label for="nights">Nights:</label>
          <input type="text" name="nights" id="nights">
          <span>*</span><br>
          <label>Adults:</label>
          <select name="adults" id="adults">
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
           <option value="4">4</option>                              
          </select><br>
          <label>Children:</label>
          <select name="children" id="children">
           <option value="0">0</option>
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
           <option value="4">4</option>                              
          </select><br>         
      </div><!--tab1: genInfo-->
      
      <div id="tabs-2">
       <label>Room type:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="room" id="standard" class="left" checked>Standard&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;          
    <input type="radio" name="room" id="business" class="left">Business&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="room" id="suite" class="left last">Suite<br>
          <label>Bed type:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="bed" id="king" class="left" checked>King&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="bed" id="double" class="left last">Double Double<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="smoking" id="smoking">Smoking<br>
      </div> <!--tab2: Pref-->
      
      <div id="tabs-3">
       <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <span>*</span><br>
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
          <span>*</span><br>
    <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="999-999-9999">
    <span>*</span><br>
   </div> <!--tab3: contactInfo-->
   
     </div> <!--end tabs div-->
    

     
      <input type="button" id="policies" value="View Cancellation Policies">
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Request">
   <div id="dialog" title="Cancellation Policies" style="display: none;">
    <p>Notification of cancellation or arrival date change must be 
    received more than three days (72 hours) prior to the confirmed arrival date for the 
    reservation deposit to be refundable. Email notification is acceptable, and a cancellation
    confirmation will be sent to you. Failure to check-in on the scheduled arrival date 
    will result in the cancellation of the reservation including any remaining nights, 
    and the reservation deposit shall be forfeited.</p>
   </div><br>      
     

 </form>
 <script src="reservationTab.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```